# Is it possible to use the Flow Name of a visual workflow to populate a field on the record that was created by the Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, field-update, flow

I have a flow that creates a case record and would like to populate a field on the new case record with the Flow Name. So I basically need to track which flow created the case record. I have had no luck finding any answers to this so any help or guidance would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could populate a custom field witht the flow name when new record is created you may track looking at the filed values.if there is already one such process is there or not confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the case record from the Flow - why not populating your field on the Record Create /Record Update module - you can just write the Name of the Flow as you like it to appear in Text Field youre updating you can also add - 
{!$Flow.CurrentDateTime} to know time the Flow update it. 

maybe you can use the Record Lookup on FlowInterview Object and retrieve some more of the Flow Properties if you need them.. (This I'm not sure..)